# Array with object sorting with Underscore sortBy

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, underscore.js

I have this array. How do I use underscore '_.sortBy' to sort it according to start date?

```
[
    { 
        id: 'oljw832021kjnb389xzll323jk',
        start: { dateTime: '2013-09-26T13:30:00-07:00' },
        end: { dateTime: '2013-09-26T14:30:00-07:00' },
    },
    { 
        id: 'ed7l5tmckdp0lm90nvr4is3d4c',
        start: { dateTime: '2013-09-26T15:30:00-07:00' },
        end: { dateTime: '2013-09-26T16:30:00-07:00' },
    },
    { 
        id: 'etmasdsackdp0kjl0nvrkopioqw',
        start: { dateTime: '2013-09-26T18:00:00-07:00' },
        end: { dateTime: '2013-09-26T19:00:00-07:00' },
    }
]
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Use an iterator function, not a single string for a property:

```
_.sortBy(arr, function(o) { return o.start.dateTime; })
```

Comment: it gives in ascending order, but how to sort it descending order of date ?

Comment: @RobinAT: You simply could negate the datetime

Comment: if you want to do descending order, then just do arr.reverse()

Comment: if you want descending order of date then use below `_.sortBy(arr, function(o) { var dt = new Date(o.start.dateTime); return -dt; })`

Comment: @imdadhusen: Yes, that's what I meant when I said "*negate the datetime*". However, that `Date` object is superfluous, you can just do `return -o.start.dateTime;`

Comment: I was looking for a way to sort by `id` (not nested). For this `_sortBy('id')` is enough. Thanks!

Comment: Lodash `_.orderBy` is meant for descending order. https://lodash.com/docs/#orderBy

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way:

```
var sorted = _(list).sortBy(
                    function (item) {                        
                        return [new Date(item.effectiveDate).getTime(), item.batchId];
                    }), "batchId");
```

If you want it descending then it's the same thing but *-1

```
var sorted = _(list).sortBy(
                    function (item) {                        
                        return [new Date(item.effectiveDate).getTime()*-1, item.batchId];
                    }), "batchId");
```

In this example I am ordering by two fields, you can forget about the item.batchId.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

var sortedItem = _.sortBy(yourArrayName, ["start"])