# How to sort Date in descending order in underscore.js?

Tags: underscore.js

Is there a function available in underscore.js to sort an array of date in descending order?

Answer (score 5):

A more complete answer has been asked on Stack Overflow before, fwiw. I think this is also a great answer to the question, provided by @Bergi :

It's the same answer as @Praveen's, but it includes an example detailing the property checking for date comparisons, i.e. if you're "time model" is {"start": {"dateTime": ...}, "end": {"dateTime": ...} }, then you can sort via:

```
_.sortBy(arr, function(o) { return o.start.dateTime; })
```

Thanks to @Praveen and @Bergi!

[StackOverflow QA Thread - Underscore, SortBy, Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090626/array-with-object-sorting-with-underscore-sortby)

Answer (score 1):

***[_.sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)***

Splits a collection into sets, grouped by the result of running each value through iteratee. If iteratee is a string instead of a function, groups by the property named by iteratee on each of the values.

For sorting desc, you can ***[reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)*** the array after sorting.