# How to sort a set of data by date in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Does anybody know how to sort out a set of data in appcelerator? I tried out with some sample code and it worked fine. But while implementing in my scenario it's not working. In my case I added data into the DB and sorted it by calling data from DB. Date format is like this "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

Here is my code:

```
var DummyData = [];
var isDatess=true;

var sampleData= Alloy.createCollection('samplePage');
sampleData .fetch({query:"SELECT * FROM dummyValfromDB"});
if(sampleData.length > 0){
        isDatess=true;
        for (var i = 0; i < sampleData.length;i++) {
        var did = sampleData.at(i).get('did');
        var dummyName = sampleData.at(i).get('dummyName');
        var dummydate= sampleData.at(i).get('dummydate');
        var dummyuid= sampleData.at(i).get('dummyuid');

        sampleData.push({
             "label_dummy_name": { text: dummyName},
             "label_dummydate":{text: dummydate},
             "label_dummyuid":{text: dummyuid},      
        });
    }
        DummyData.sort(sorting);
}

  function sorting(a,b){  
    var dateA = new Date(a.label_dummydate).getTime();
    var dateB = new Date(b.label_dummydate).getTime();
    var result="";
    if(isDatess)
        result=dateA > dateB ? 1 : -1;  
    else
        result=dateA < dateB ? 1 : -1;
    return result;  

  }; 


$.dummyList.sections[0].setItems(DummyData);
```

Comment: Presuming that the format you pass to *Date* can be parsed correctly (and there's a very high chance that it won't in at least some browsers), then the sort function can be greatly simplified to something like this: `return new Date(a.label_dummydate) - new Date(b.label_dummydate)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer. NaN shows while executing and it resolved by adding text. Find the answer i got below.

```
  function sorting(a,b) {  
            var valA = a.label_dummydate.text;
            var valB = b.label_dummydate.text;

            var dateA = new Date(val_a).getTime();
            var dateB = new Date(val_b).getTime();
            var result="";

            if(isDatess)
                result=dateA > dateB ? 1 : -1;  
            else
                result=dateA < dateB ? 1 : -1;  
            return result;  
      };
```

Thanks for all your help. I think it may help somebody....Cheers !!!!

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, can you use  ORDER BY in your SQL query to sort the data by date or date time either ascending or descending?

Comment: Hi... yes i did that and it works fine for me. But not from otherside in some scenarios. So i just put a soring in the code itself. Find the code that i posted. It works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This is only a quick glance, but it looks like you are using a.label_dummydate in your date constructor in your sorting function when you should be using a.label_dummydate.text. What you are using is an object literal as opposed to the string content you want so its making an invalid date which won't compare correctly

Answer (score 0):

Sorting can be done by using the `Underscorejs` library which is available built-in with Alloy.

You can use the `_.sortBy()` for you case. Refer this for [usage](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)

Also this post specifically talks about sorting dates using underscore sortBy.
[Array with object sorting with Underscore sortBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090626/array-with-object-sorting-with-underscore-sortby)

Answer (score 0):

Alloy has [moment.js](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/MomentJS) built-in, in my opinion it is easier than Date (both to work with and read the code), also it provides a lot of utilities to compare two dates; if you are interested into internationalization also it is quite easy to do it.